# Multiple Post Callback request in Nodejs Express?

Tags: node.js, express, post

Currently i have a single view with both login and Signup Form to post a request to home now i want to call multiple function to access home from both signup and login Form How should i use it?

a)

```
app.post('/', functionA(req , res ,next){
}, functionB(req , res ,next){
});
```

or should I call it as

b)

`app.post('/' , login, signup);`

```
function login(req , res ,next){

 };

 function signup(req , res ,next){

 };
```

or something else?

Comment: Acc. to me the API endpoints for login and signup should be different completely.

app.post('/login', loginHandler) and app.post("/signup", signUpHandler).

Comment: they are from single page /index is it possible to have a diff end point

Comment: yes.. May I know how you are trying to hint these endpoints

Comment: Why not just add different endpoints for login and signup?

Comment: which endpoints?
both forms are posting data into /home

Comment: @tjugg how to ?

Comment: app.post('/login', function(req, res) {...} -- app.post('/signUp', function(req, res) {...} ?

Comment: and render the same view?

Comment: Well, if that's what you want to do? I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could have different handlers for login and signup :

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  // login code here
  res.redirect('/') // redirect to the get request of the home page if you want or make the response you want
})

app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
  // signup code here
  res.redirect('/')
})
```

and in the html page make each form point to its handler:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
  <!-- login form -->
</form>

<form action="/signup" method="post">
  <!-- signup form -->
</form>
```

Comment: then how to get /home from this

Comment: You can use `res.redirect('/home')` instead or the `res.redirect('/')` to go to the /home route after login or signup